# How do I fit unknown function to my data?

Tags: plotting, fitting, data

I have [a set of data](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OwMwGd88cvgEzgLNj1aGq4BMLu54zzNjDVhMEcXaHGg/edit?usp=sharing), to which I am trying to fit an unknown function. I believe it might be a logarithmic function, but I am not sure. Can you help me find a working model?

```
DANE = ReadList["C:\\Users\\student\\Desktop\\aj\\wyniczek.txt", Real];
l = Length[DANE]/2;
X = DANE[[1 ;; l]];
Y = DANE[[l + 1 ;; 2 l]];

dane2 = Transpose[{X, Y}];

fit = NonlinearModelFit[dane2, a0 + a1*Log[a2*x3], {a0, a1, a2}, x, 
   Method -> "NMinimize"];

Show[{ListPlot[dane2, PlotRange -> {{0, 5000}, {-100, 100}}], 
  Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 5000}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotLabel -> "Automatyczne dopasowanie wielomianu", 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you omit the first point `{0,..}` in your dataset and modify your model slightly you' ll get

```
dane2 = Rest@Transpose[{X, Y}];
fit = NonlinearModelFit[dane2, {a0 + a1*Log[ x ] }, {a0, a1 }, x,Method -> "NMinimize"];

Show[{ListPlot[dane2], Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 30000}, PlotStyle -> Red]}]
```

[image]

Comment: thx bro u help me a lot

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the Log term. The argument of Log must be a positive number. E.g., you may use "a2^2":

```
dane2 = Rest@Transpose[{X, Y}];
fit = NonlinearModelFit[dane2, {a0 + a1*Log[a2^2*x]}, {a0, a1, a2}, x]

Show[{ListPlot[dane2], 
  Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 30000}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotLabel -> "Automatyczne dopasowanie wielomianu", 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.001], Point[dane2]}]
```

[image]

Comment: In fact the `a2^2` can be removed completely, as long as you're willing to reinterpret the other parameters.  That is, `a0 + a1 Log[a2^2 x] = a0 + a1 Log[a2^2] + a1 Log[x]` which is itself a constant plus a log term that can be parameterized by `b0 + b1 Log[x]` as long as `b0 == a0 + a1 Log[a2^2]` and `a1==b1`.